# Invalid look-up value. A look-up field contains invalid data

Tags: managed-metadata, taxonomy

I have a contenttype with a TaxonomyFieldType field, which has a specific termstore and termgroup attached to it when deployed.

I didn't set `AllowMultipleValues` in my code before after the deploy so by default the field only takes singular values.

I went through the UI and set it to allow multiple values. Now when I edit a page with this contenttype and try to save it I get an error saying: **Invalid look-up value. A look-up field contains invalid data.**

If I then go back to the field and set it back to not allowing multiple values and then try to edit the page it works again, but I need it to take multiple values.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

i don't have the right answer of your problem, but each time i have to make modifications (update) on a content Type after deploy i use
[La Pointe](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2008/05/propagate-content-type-changes/)

Hope this can help you.